# Migrate from /etc/network/interfaces to netplan

Tags: linux, vlan, bridge, netplan

I am trying to migrate from /etc/network/interfaces to netplan and network-manager setup.

I am "almost" there.

My current setup with /etc/network/interfaces is as follows:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
  
auto bond0
iface bond0 inet manual
bond-slaves eno1 eno2
bond-primary eno1
bond-mode active-backup
bond-miimon 100
bond-downdelay 200
bond-updelay 40000

auto vlanbr10
iface vlanbr10 inet static
address 192.168.10.107
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.10.1
bridge-ports bond0.10
```

It is a server and I do the following things:

1. create a bond with eno1 and eno2 with active-backup
2. Add a bridge, that uses bridge-ports e.g from bond0 take vlan 10.
3. Give that server an IP in that bridge that is inside vlan10

I have conjured up the following netplan config:

```
  network:
    version: 2
    # Set ethernet interfaces configuration. Match based on mac-addresses
    ethernets:
      eno1:
        match:
          macaddress: xx:xx:xx:xx:x2
        dhcp4: no
        dhcp6: no
        set-name: eno1
      eno2:
        match:
          macaddress: xx:xx:xx:xx:x1
        dhcp4: no
        dhcp6: no
        set-name: eno2
    # Create a bond with the active ethernet interfaces that is running in active-backup mode.
    bonds:
      bond0:
        interfaces: [eno1, eno2]
        parameters:
          primary: eno1
          mode: active-backup
          mii-monitor-interval: 100
          down-delay: 200
          up-delay: 40000
        nameservers:
          addresses:
            - '8.8.8.8'
        dhcp4: false
        dhcp6: false
    bridges:
      vlanbr10:
        interfaces:
          - vlan10
        addresses: [192.168.10.109/24]
        parameters:
          forward-delay: 0
          stp: true
    vlans:
      vlan10:
        id: 10
        link: bond0
        dhcp4: false
        dhcp6: false
        accept-ra: false
```

EDIT:

Adding more information.

`netplan status` shows this output.

[image: netplan_status]

eno1 and eno2 is up and so is the bond0, but after that it gets a bit "gray".

When I am looking at the configuration of another server that is using interfaces file. Then it seems to be using bridge-ports functionality, as you can see `ip a` result from another working server is below.

```
4: bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d4:ae:52:b6:4b:3a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: vlanbr10: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d4:ae:52:b6:4b:3a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.10.107/24 brd 192.168.10.255 scope global vlanbr10
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::d6ae:52ff:feb6:4b3a/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: bond0.10@bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master vlanbr10 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d4:ae:52:b6:4b:3a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

And this last image is the `ip a` from the netplan testing machine.

[image]

As you can see, I can't really access vlan10 nor the other parts of the network. In interfaces file there is this bridge-ports option that I can't quite get my head around in netplan.

Comment: `What am I doing wrong?` - what is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I got it working, will post result here soon as an EDIT.

I needed to also add the default gateway where i specify the IP address of the server under vlanbr10.

I also needed to specify the MAC address of the bridge, to be the same as the physical interface - bond0.

```
bridges:
        vlanbr10:
            addresses:
            - 192.168.10.109/24
            interfaces:
            - vlan10
            macaddress: ae:6f:58:bd:35:1d
            parameters:
                forward-delay: 0
                stp: true
            routes:
            -   to: default
                via: 192.168.10.1
```

Courtesy here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1285193/netplan-with-bonded-nics-and-vlans-and-bridges-not-working